# Pre- and Append to a List

Tags: scala

Using scala, I try to concatenate multiple elements to a list as follows

```
val min = func1()
val max = func1()
val interpol : List[Float] = func2()

val res : List[Float] = (min.toFloat) :: interpolated :: (max.toFloat) :: Nil
```

This syntax does not work because of a type mismatch error. How could I pre- and append elements to a list (in a very elegant way, i.e., without using list buffers, etc.)?

Btw, I also tried

```
val res : List[Float] = (min.toFloat) :: interpolated :: List(max.toFloat)
```

but  got a type mismatch error (`List[Any]` vs `List[Float]`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Peter Neyens solution works fine.
Personally, i prefer this one

```
min.toFloat +: interpolated :+ max.toFloat
```

`+:` and `:+` are defines in Seq, so works not only for `List`, but for `Vector` too

Answer (score 2):

You are prepending the `min.toFloat` to the `interpolated` list, but you can't prepend the resulting list to the list with the maximum you have created (`max.toFloat :: Nil`), you will need `:::` to concatenate these two lists.

```
(min.toFloat) :: interpolated ::: ((max.toFloat) :: Nil)
```